# Is intel_extension_for_pytorch compatible with anaconda?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, intel

I have an intel gpu which is not cuda compatible, so I'm spending a lot of time training small-ish nets on my cpu.  I found that there is a package called `intel_extension_for_pytorch` that is available to run on pytorch.  When trying to install it in my Anaconda environment though, I receive the error:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - intel_extension_for_pytorch

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org
```

I have read the ReadMe for the package, and visited their installation guide, but found nothing mentioning conda installation, only for pip.

How to get it working?

https://github.com/intel/intel-extension-for-pytorch

Answer (score 0):

https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment
sometimes there is no conda.. its possible to use both, though pip doesnt do versioning as well as conda.